# Does Search Console 404s from relative path links affect Crawl Budget?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, googlebot, 404

Search Console is reporting 404s for URLs that don't exist on my site. However, GoogleBot seems to be crawling a URL by guessing a page based off of relative paths in my links. For example:

I have a page `http://www.example.com/joe/product/cool-product`

It contains a relative link: `<a href="/art/modern">modern art</a>`

I seem to be getting a lot of 404s in Search Console for `http://www.example.com/joe/product/art/modern`

Which doesn't exist and I can only assume the GoogleBot is building this URL from the current page URL and the path in a strange way.

**Does this affect my Crawl Budget?**

Comment: Googlebot is crawling them.  Everything Googlebot crawls is part of your sites "crawl budget".

Comment: Googlebot has a big budget. Most sites don't have to worry about having more pages than Google is willing to crawl.

Answer (score 1):

- Crawl rate limit is designed to help Google not crawl your pages too
  much and too fast where it hurts your server.
- Crawl demand is how much Google wants to crawl your pages. This is
  based on how popular your pages are and how stale the content is in
  the Google index.
- **Crawl budget** is “taking crawl rate and crawl demand together.” Google
  defines crawl budget as “the number of URLs Googlebot can and wants
  to crawl.”

For more read: [**here.**](http://searchengineland.com/google-explains-crawl-budget-means-webmasters-267597)